# Is it okay to assign a value after starting an activity?

Tags: java, android

Imagine that I assign a value to a boolean for example immediately after calling `startActivity(intent)` . Will the value be assigned after or before the intent is started?

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), activityMyClass);
        startActivity(intent);
        my_boolean=true;
```

apparently my_boolean is true after executing these lines of code, but why is it working if the app will go to another activity before the boolean assignment ?

Comment: What are you doing with the boolean? And why can you not use `Intent#putExtra`?

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is "whether when the program reaches `startActivity` and a new activity appears, the previous activity stops on that line?"

No, Your activity is an object that remains in RAM, and the code written after `startActivity` is executed normally.

You probably wrote the code you shared in a `View.OnClickListener` and Android calls it when the view you specified is clicked and executes its codes, in the middle of the codes there is `startAcitivity` which is executed like other functions and also the codes are executed until the end of the onClick function.